# Accessing a vhost on a LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, lamp, virtualhost

I have a LAMP server configured to server VHOSTs. The problem here is that when I try to access it through the same LAN, I seem to try and access the local IP address and not the VHOST address. However, when I try to access the server from outside, it displays the right VHOST. I need to configure apache to somehow serve the right site and not the default site. How do I do this?

Here is an example of two of my VHOST entries.

**Default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin [email]
    ServerName eresk.fi

    DocumentRoot /home/web/apache-webserver/public_html/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/web/apache-webserver/public_html/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/web/apache-webserver/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/home/web/apache-webserver/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Another site**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin [email]
    ServerName diggety.net
    ServerAlias *.diggety.net

    DocumentRoot /home/web/diggety/public_html/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/web/diggety/public_html/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/web/diggety/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/home/web/diggety/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule php5_mod.c>
            php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800
    </IfModule>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_diggety.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_diggety.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not apache's fault. VirtualHost directives do not work for requests via IP.  The computer in your LAN from which you are accessing the site checks DNS servers and gets external IP as a result. If server is on the same network, then a proper router on your network should resolve/route it properly, but this is not always the case with some routers.

To test this, on a client add custom DNS entry for you domain mapping it to internal ip of your server. Edit `/etc/hosts` if client is linux or `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` if client on Windows and add this (change 10.0.0.1 with internal IP of your server):

```
10.0.0.1 domain.com
```

**Update**:
If the solution with DNS works, what you can do is configure custom DNS server on your internal network which would allow you to set custom DNS entries. This way you will not need to set it manually on clients.

Comment: Sure, I have done this. But I'd like to configure the router or whatever to not have to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of router do you have? In my experience low-end consumer routers would just not route requests correctly to external IP (either NAT or port forwarding would not work correctly). When using business-class routers (had good experience with Cicso, Linksys or some TrendNet models) or a firewall distribution like pfSense it is not a problem.

Comment: If the solution with DNS works, what you can do is configure custom DNS server on your internal network which would allow you to set custom DNS entries. This way you will not need to set it manually on clients. I can't think of any other solutions.

Comment: One option worth considering is to configure the webserver with separate IPs per vhost. You can specify a single IP address (or a few) with `NameVirtualHost` directives. The other IP addresses you can then specify in the `VirtualHost` directives. Each VirtualHost directive would then list all of the shared IP addresses plus the one assigned to that specific vhost. I have used it to configure a webserver that uses name based on IPv4 and IP based on IPv6, but it works equally well with just RFC1918 addresses.

Comment: But how would this let him resolve `domain.com` to a LAN IP? Because from what I understand, he wants that to work.

Comment: @edvinas.me The router I use is not any cheap default router. It is a ZyXEL ZyWALL USG 20. Any ideas about it?